# Shape Erorr when using Bidirectional instead of standard LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When switching to a Bidirectional layer my code gives an error. The model works when using the standard LSTM layers. The error I got is:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-1e9000cb0bf6>", line 12, in <module>
model.build(input_shape)
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_11: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

My code looks like this:

```
input_shape = (lengtharray,1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.build(input_shape)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss'),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
model.summary()
```

Why does it return a shape error when using a Bidirectional instead of standard LSTM?

Answer (score 0):

I can not test your code (because I am on the move), but if you define the `input_shape` outside the `CuDNN` but inside `Bidirectional` then it should work. So something like this

`Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True),input_shape=input_shape)`

THe thing is Bidirectional behaves liek LSTM so it will require arguments like LSTM as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Bidirectional#call_arguments). For a Bidirectional example you can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#bidirectional_rnns).